# Returning all values when SPROC variable is NULL

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to return 'all' categories from the following just by leaving the `SPROC` input variable *completely* blank?

CLARIFICATION - without even using the ''

```
CREATE TABLE Levels (ID INT PRIMARY KEY
                    ,Value INT 
                    ,Category VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO Levels VALUES(1, 30, 'High') 
                        ,(2, 20, 'Medium') 
                        ,(3, 10, 'Low') 
GO

CREATE PROC LevelValues @Category VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM Levels
WHERE Category = CASE @Category WHEN '' THEN Category ELSE @Category END
END
GO

EXEC LevelValues ''
```

Comment: Why the question? The code you have already does that except for any null `Category` but your example data doesn't show any nulls.

Comment: Sorry , I want to return all Categories without even having to use the ' '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use your SP without passing any value to your parameter like this:

```
CREATE PROC LevelValues @Category VARCHAR(10) = ''
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM Levels
WHERE Category = CASE @Category WHEN '' THEN Category ELSE @Category END
END
GO

EXEC LevelValues
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROC LevelValues @Category VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM Levels
WHERE Category = @Category OR @Category = ''
END
```

After your comment, here's another solution:

```
CREATE PROC LevelValues @Category VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN

IF @Category = ''
    SELECT * 
    FROM Levels
ELSE
    SELECT * 
    FROM Levels
    WHERE Category = @Category    
END
```

Comment: Sorry I meant without even using the ''

Comment: Thanks! This happens too often, I'm getting a bit tired of it :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like

```
SELECT * FROM Levels WHERE Category = @Category OR @Category = ''
```

This should return all the records when the input is empty

ELSE

```
SELECT * FROM Levels WHERE Category = @Category OR @Category = NULL
```

Comment: Sorry I meant without even using the ''